# How to run pipeline only on pull request to master branch

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Bitbucket pipelines allows to define checks on pull-requests and has glob filter that allows checking source branch.

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**': #this runs as default for any branch not elsewhere defined
      - step:
          script:
            - ...
    feature/*: #any branch with a feature prefix
      - step:
          script:
            - ...
```

How to filter based on target branch? There are some tests that need to be done only when merging into master.

Comment: For clarity the first `script` needs a `:` after it; `script:`.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sadly indeed, the pull-request pipeline mechanism is working based on the source branch, not on the target branch.

This is explained on the issue from their tracker adding the `pull-request` feature by one of the team member:

> The branch pattern under pull requests defines the source branch. This
> is so that you can run a different pipeline depending on the fix. For
> example you may have a different set of tests for feature branches vs
> hotfix branches. Note that this is only talking about the tests that
> run against the PR during development.

***Source:** [Geoff Crain's comment](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/13438/add-specific-pipelines-configuration-for#comment-49819070)*

There is actually another issue open for [this exact feature](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/17859/pull-request-for-pipeline-based-on).

But the answer from the team is:

> I can definitely see why this would be useful, especially when merging
> to the master/main branch.
>
> Given our current priorities, however, this is unlikely something that
> we'll support in the short term. In the meantime though, I'll open
> this ticket to gauge the interest of other users in seeing the same
> thing.

***Source**: [Aneita Yang's comment](https://bitbucket.org/site/master/issues/17859/pull-request-for-pipeline-based-on#comment-49684624)*

That said, you could somehow have the required behavior with this kind of hack:

```yaml
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**': #this runs as default for any branch not elsewhere defined
      - step:
          script:
            - if [ "${BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH}" != "master" ]; then printf 'not a target branch we want to check'; exit; fi
            - printf 'running useful tests'
```

Or, if you already are doing some tests on all pull request, like I understand it:

```yaml
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**': #this runs as default for any branch not elsewhere defined
      - step:
          script:
            - printf 'these are the all PR tests'
            - if [ "${BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH}" = "master" ]; then printf 'those are the extra checks on master'; fi
```

Or yet again, it could be externalized to a script on its own:

*bitbucket-pipelines.yaml*

```yaml
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**': #this runs as default for any branch not elsewhere defined
      - step:
          script:
            - ./bin/tests "${BITBUCKET_PR_DESTINATION_BRANCH}"
```

*bin/tests*

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

printf 'these are the all PR tests'

if [ "${1}" = "master" ]
then 
    printf 'those are the extra checks on master'
fi
```

**See also**: Variables in pipelines documentation page: https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/variables-in-pipelines-794502608.html