# Bitbucket pull requests pipeline with specific glob patterns

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

I am little confused here regarding PR being triggered against main branch?

All branches:
`(I know this will trigger pull request from any branch to any branch)`

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':
```

Main branch:
`(Does this trigger pull request if created from feature/pe-1234 to main?)`

```
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    'main':
```

I want to know what happens if I mention only `main`. It is not clear in documentation or may be I didn't get it right

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/q/55019205/11715259

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The branch name / glob pattern in the pull-request pipeline definition is the **source** branch that should trigger that pipeline, not the target branch.

E.g. if you were following git-flow instead of github-flow, it would make sense to override the pipeline run by the PR from `main` to a `release/whatever` branch so that it simply passes, or does an integration test, but does not perform the usual tests, linting, coverage and whatnot.

```yaml
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':  # triggers if no other specific pipeline was triggered
      - parallel:
          - step: *linting-step
          - step: *testing-step
    main:  # triggers from main to anywhere else
      - step:
          name: Pass
          script:
            - exit 0
```

If following github-flow, you will probably never make a PR from `main` to anywhere else, so you can safely skip this definition. Only if you wanted PRs from `feature/AAA-NNNN` branches to trigger a special pipeline besides the testing workflow, you can write an alternate pipeline like

```yaml
pipelines:
  pull-requests:
    '**':  # triggers if no other specific pipeline was triggered
      - parallel:
          - step: *linting-step
          - step: *testing-step
    feature/*:  # triggers from feature/* to anywhere else (including to main)
      - parallel:
          - step: *linting-step
          - step: *testing-step
          - step: *maybe-hook-issue-tracker-step # ?
```

so that the simpler default `'**'` pipeline will not run. But it will run irrespective of the target branch, usually `main` but not necessarily.